# ASP.NET MVC 4 + SimpleMembershipProvider

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, simplemembership

My MVC application works perfectly in the development machine but when I deploy into the  production server it always gives various error messages, for example:

> You must call the "WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection" method before you call any other method of the "WebSecurity" class. This call should be placed in an _AppStart.cshtml file in the root of your site.

WebMatrix.WebData've changed the version to 2.0 and set Copy Local = true to, and I copied these lines into the web.config:

```
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="SimpleRoleProvider">
 <providers>
  <clear/>
  <add name="SimpleRoleProvider" type="WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleRoleProvider,WebMatrix.WebData"/>
 </providers>
</roleManager>
<membership defaultProvider="SimpleMembershipProvider">
 <providers>
 <clear/>
 <add name="SimpleMembershipProvider" type="WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider, WebMatrix.WebData" />
 </providers>
</membership>
```

I do not know what the reason is.
I need help.

Comment: Did you call WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection from the _AppStart.cshtml file?

Comment: @Andorbal he is working with MVC app, not web pages. `_AppStart.cshtml` does not exist when you work with MVC, atleast not `MVC3 or MVC4`

Comment: I've put the initialization code in the method Application_Start() of the Global.asax but the error is the same. Otherwise the code is the same.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with simpleMembership, i would encourage that you take a look at this [BlogPost](http://blog.spontaneouspublicity.com/including-asp-net-simple-membership-tables-as-part-of-your-entity-framework-model), it was really helpful in my case as it keeps you in control of all the membership tables and also make them **Part of Your Entity Framework Model**

Anyways, there should be a `InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute.cs` file in the Filters directory of your MVC project. Go to that file and take this:

```
if (!WebSecurity.Initialized)
            WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DefaultConnection", "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);
```

and put it into `Global.asax.cs` file. This way it will always be initialized. Also after you do this, there is not need to keep `InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute.cs` and i would suggest that you take `[InitializeSimpleMembership]` off your `AcccountController`

Comment: I did it but now this error message appears in the first line of the Index method of the HomeController : "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: @sada follow the link to the blog i posted, you may need to restart what you are doing and do it right. By the way, that error just means that you are trying to call a `null` entry.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Finally, it was found that the installation went wrong.